# What should go in an inflatable sleeping pad repair kit?

Tags: backpacking, sleeping, sleeping-pads

While backpacking with an inflatable or self-inflating sleeping pad one runs the risk of getting holes in it.

This does happen fairly frequently, and while they do make kits, I would like to know what should be in such a kit if I were to purchase one or what components I would need if I wanted to put one together myself.

What would I need to have with me to fix the leak in the backcountry?

Comment: You can get patch kits for air mattresses. Most new ones come with patch kits. They're a pretty standard item in most all camping stores.

Comment: I suggest that you ask for the pros and cons of inflatable vs foam pads.  It is a more basic question.

Comment: @ab2 See this question http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15437/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-air-pads-vs-foam-pads-for-backpacking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many manufacturers of inflatable sleeping pads sell repair kits.

Duct tape could be used in an emergency, but I would only use it as a last resort as it will leave a residue on your sleeping pad when you get back home and want to repair it properly.

Most kits will have something like the following items in them:

- Seam Grip Sealer & Adhesive
- Tenacious Tape Repair Tape or Tenacious Tape Repair Patches
- Small patch brush

[image: Seam Grip Field Repair Kit]

[Seam Grip Field Repair Kit](https://www.gearaid.com/blogs/learn/repair-sleeping-pad)

If I were to make my own repair kit I would add a few more items to make it a little bit more usable on other things.

- Pencil or Sharpie to mark where the leak is
- Rubbing alcohol to clean the spot
- Cotton swabs to used with rubbing alcohol
- Small pair of scissors to cut tape instead of just tearing it
- small piece of very fine sandpaper to roughen up smooth surfaces if need be so the glue can bound better

Comment: Note that there are other urethane-based sealants, if you don't have any Seam Grip.